# Is it possible to send two Authorization Header (Bearer and Basic)

Tags: ajax, basic-authentication, bearer-token

This is how I setup my ajax with Bearer token for Authorization Header:

```
let headerParams = {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
};
let url = "url.com";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    headers: headerParams,
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (error) {
    },
});
```

However on the test server, we also use Basic Auth to access the site. How should I add both Basic and Bearer token in the ajax?

Below is the ajax that works when I only use Basic Authorization Header

```
let headerParams = {
    Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(username + ": " + password),
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
};
let url = "url.com";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    headers: headerParams,
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (error) {
    },
});
```

I tried adding the Bearer and Basic in headerParams like below:

```
let headerParams = {
    Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(username + ": " + password),
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
};
```

But it does not really work since this will overwrite the previous Authorization. I also added Bearer in headerParams while the Basic auth in beforeSend callback, the same error `401` for missing basic auth and `500` in the backend since backend is unable to authenticate user. Most of the SO questions that I have read only uses one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You may try sending the header as:

```
Authorization: Bearer <accessToken>, Basic <btoa(username + ": " + password)>
```

It actually depends more on the server than the client and whether it accepts the multi value. So, please try it out.

According to the spec [RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.2), section 3.2.2, Field Order:

> A sender MUST NOT generate multiple header fields with the same field
> name in a message unless either the entire field value for that header
> field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)] or the
> header field is a well-known exception (as noted below).
>
> A recipient MAY combine multiple header fields with the same field
> name into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the
> semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field value to
> the combined field value in order, separated by a comma. The order in
> which header fields with the same field name are received is therefore
> significant to the interpretation of the combined field value; a proxy
> MUST NOT change the order of these field values when forwarding a
> message.

Comment: when you say it will depend on server, are you referring to how the middleware will handle the data?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth that's correct, since you can add information but if the handling in server-side does not take into account such scenarios, it will be meaningless. For example imagine an Auth filter that expects only `Bearer xxx` and as a naive implementation takes the `Authorization` header => removes "Bearer" from the string => assumes that resulting value is a token. This middleware would fail if you send multiple values in the `Authorization` header